# Is there a way to detect and prevent a specific Chrome extension using the window object?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

There have been instances where user information is being leaked through a Chrome extension. Is there a way to detect and prevent a specific Chrome extension using the window object?

Before they inject dom in out document. So we can block extension in a way observing dom id. but now they using new window when user activate extension... is there any way to block extension?

I found chrome object in window. but nothing that i can handle...

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want to block and what "they using new window" means. It may help with a workaround, even though generally it's impossible to prevent extensions from running.